# How can I resolve this Cmake Error When Installing TrajOpt to my catkin workspace?

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-18.04, ros

I'm trying to install [TrajOpt](http://rll.berkeley.edu/trajopt/doc/sphinx_build/html/install.html) to my catkin workspace. I have gotten up to `make -j`. See my terminal output below.

How do I proceed? Thank you in advance!

```
$ make -j
Scanning dependencies of target json
Scanning dependencies of target utils
Scanning dependencies of target bpmpd_caller
Scanning dependencies of target gtest
[  1%] Building CXX object src/sco/CMakeFiles/bpmpd_caller.dir/bpmpd_caller.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object src/utils/CMakeFiles/utils.dir/stl_to_string.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object src/utils/CMakeFiles/utils.dir/config.cpp.o
[  7%] Building CXX object src/utils/CMakeFiles/utils.dir/logging.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object src/utils/CMakeFiles/utils.dir/clock.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object ext/json/CMakeFiles/json.dir/src/lib_json/json_value.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object ext/json/CMakeFiles/json.dir/src/lib_json/json_reader.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object ext/json/CMakeFiles/json.dir/src/lib_json/json_writer.cpp.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object ext/gtest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o
[ 18%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/bpmpd_caller
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(bpmdll.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(mprnt.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(pddrv.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(readpar.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(rowact.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(rowdup.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(rowsng.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(scale.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(wrimps.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(aggreg.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(bndchk.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(bpmpd.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(cdiag.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(cdircc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(cdirpc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(cfixvar.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(chepdu.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(coldbl.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(colsng.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(cstpcrt.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(cstplen.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(dblrow.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(duchek.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(facts5c.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(factsnb3.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(fbtran8.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(itrefsol.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(lindep.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(nfacts5c.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(nfactsb3.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(pbcgm.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(pbqmr.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(refactm.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(rngchk.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(setlam.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(sparsr.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(supnode.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(symfactq.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(symmfo.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(unroll.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(warmstrt.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(affsdir.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(ordctl.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(metis.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(mfillind.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sophie/caris_ws/trajopt/3rdpartylib/bpmpd_linux64.a(mfillin.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/sco/CMakeFiles/bpmpd_caller.dir/build.make:95: recipe for target 'bin/bpmpd_caller' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/bpmpd_caller] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:286: recipe for target 'src/sco/CMakeFiles/bpmpd_caller.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/sco/CMakeFiles/bpmpd_caller.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 20%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libjson.so
[ 20%] Built target json
[ 21%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libutils.so
[ 21%] Built target utils
[ 23%] Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libgtest.a
[ 23%] Built target gtest
Makefile:94: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: A name of variable (`GUROBI_LIBRARY`) suggests that the error is about the gurobi library. Do you have it installed?

Comment: Thanks! Maybe that's the problem. I'm going to check my gurobi installation

Comment: I checked my gurobi insulation and fixed the issue with my license. I edited my question as a result of this

Comment: They said the commit in that [pull request](https://github.com/ros-industrial-consortium/trajopt_ros/pull/19) has fixed the issue. Make sure that you are trying to install newest Trajopt version.

Comment: Oh, so I should have cloned from that repo? How come the installation page pointed me to this repo https://github.com/joschu/trajopt

Comment: Well, it seems that given [pull request](https://github.com/ros-industrial-consortium/trajopt_ros/pull/19) is newer than the last commit to the repo you use. You may try to manually apply [diff](https://github.com/ros-industrial-consortium/trajopt_ros/pull/19/commits/81793b379240b1dada352a625be4f130e081928c) for that pull request to the [src/sco/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/joschu/trajopt/blob/master/src/sco/CMakeLists.txt). I am expert in neither trajopt nor ROS, so cannot suggest anything more.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It looks like the master trajopt repository hasn't been updated in a couple years, but there's a forked repository which has some recent branches, and [this branch at this link](https://github.com/cedriclmenard/trajopt/tree/fixes-cedric) has solved that error for me. Then, I was running into another issue, which I was able to resolve by following [these instructions](https://github.com/joschu/trajopt/issues/20#issuecomment-568389653).

Checkout new trajopt branch:

```
git checkout https://github.com/cedriclmenard/trajopt.git
cd trajopt
git checkout --track origin/fixes-cedric
```

Fixes for new error:

```
sudo apt-get install libopenscenegraph-dev
sudo cp /usr/include/osg/CameraNode usr/local/include/osg/
sudo apt-get remove libopenscenegraph-dev
```

Finish making trajopt (I added 1 to the  make command that way I didn't get a "out of memory" error):

```
cd ..
mkdir build_trajopt
cmake path/to/trajopt
make -j 1
```